# Proof for a formula for trace of positive integer power of matrix

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, trace

I am looking for a possible proof of a formula.

I have been trying working on matrices and observed a pattern for the trace of positive integer power of the following matrix-
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&a\\0&b&0\\c&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
which is $$Tr(A^n) = \begin{cases}
a^n, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{$n$ odd} \\
a^n+2b^{n/2} c^{n/2},\,\,\,\,\, \text{$n$ even}\\
\end{cases}$$

What could possibly be the proof of this formula other than the iterative approach?

(i.e. if we try proving this formula as a theorem)

Please suggest some proof.
Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: The matrix is diagonalizable, its eigen values are $b$ and $\pm \sqrt{ac}$. This means that the eigen values of $A^n$ are $b^n$, $(ac)^{n/2}$ and $(-1)^n (ac)^{n/2}$. So the trace is the sum of that : $b^n+(1+(-1)^n) (ac)^{n/2}$.

Comment: In this case, since $A^2$ itself is diagonal, we can compute $A^n$ directly as either $(A^2)^k$ if $n=2k$ is even or $(A^2)^kA$ if $n=2k+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Let$$P=\begin{bmatrix}0&-\sqrt a&\sqrt a\\1&0&0\\0&\sqrt c&\sqrt c\end{bmatrix};$$the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors of $A$ and$$P^{-1}.A.P=\begin{bmatrix}b&0&0\\0&-\sqrt a\sqrt c&0\\0&0&\sqrt a\sqrt c\end{bmatrix}.$$So,$$\operatorname{tr}(A^n)=\operatorname{tr}\left(\begin{bmatrix}b^n&0&0\\0&\left(-\sqrt a\sqrt c\right)^n&0\\0&0& \left(\sqrt a\sqrt c\right)^n\end{bmatrix}\right).$$

---

You can also use the fact that$$A^n=\begin{cases}\begin{bmatrix}a^{n/2}c^{n/2}&0&0\\0&b^n&0\\0&0&a^{n/2}c^{n/2}\end{bmatrix}&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\\begin{bmatrix}0&0&a^{(n+1)/2}c^{(n-1)/2}\\0&b^n&0\\a^{(n-1)/2}c^{(n+1)/2}&0&0\end{bmatrix}&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$a fact that can easily be proved by induction.

Comment: Thankyou very much for replying. .but I didn't understand the proof quite well. .Could you please explain it a bit more sir?

Comment: Also, how did you choose that matrix P?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I defined $P$ as a matrix whose columns are eigenvectors of $A$. Whenever you do that to a $n\times n$ matrix $M$ then, if the columns of $P$ are $n$ linearly independent vectors, the matrix $P^{-1}MP$ is always a diagonal matrix (and the entries of the main diagonal are the eigenvalues of $M$).

Comment: Other than that, what do you want me to explain?